# JS slideshow works on firefox and chrome but not internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

My  customer gallery' slideshow works on firefox and chrome but not internet explorer for some reason. 
I have a few of these kind of slideshows on my site and they are all behaving the same way.
It was changed fairly recently so that it didn't conflict with the dropdown menus and I think this may have caused it...

http://www.macgregorandmacduff.co.uk/kilts-social

this is the section of code that relates to the slideshow...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sshow/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sshow/jsscriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder">     
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sshow/js/lightbox.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="sshow/css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />



<script src="sshow/Scripts/AC_RunActiveContent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="sshow/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-25993448-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
```

})();

```
</script>

<h3>Customer Gallery</h3>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Iain

Comment: this is the section of code that concerns the slideshow...

Answer (score 0):

ie console says:

object is NULL or undefined
lightbox.js, line 226 symbol 20